# Random walk with Ammonia molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, statistics, diffusion

This question is from Keith Stowe's Introduction to Thermodynamics book under Random walk.
The question is something like this:

[image]

[image]

I am aware that I am not supposed to post homework questions like this without any attempted solutions, but I am struggling to understand what the question is asking. So, what does it mean by more than 32% of ammonia molecules when I am not given the total number of molecules to begin with? Just a hint towards the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if the initial quantity is not given to you, that means it isn't relevant. In other words, you could assign $N=100$ or $1000$ or $10^{23}$ , it won't change the answer. You could either reason as to why this might be true, or try it out with different $N$ or **$N$ as a variable** (this is definitely the right way to go as you would do this even if you were assigned a particular value of $N$), and see if it depends.